# Put a link on home screen of my app and connect it to WebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

In my app i want to put my website's url on home screen and on clicking on it i want it to be open as a WebView.
How should i go for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous commenter is incorrect. You can open any hyperlink either externally with Safari or internally with a UIWebView.

Add a UIWebViewController to your project. Then, instantiate an instance of a the UIWebViewController that will be shown inside your app--you'll do this by declaring a property & synthesizing it within your main view controller (which will need to be declared as a UIWebViewDelegate), such as:

```
@interface MyMainViewController: UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    // Your implementation code here
}
```

When a user taps the button (assuming you make it a button, rather than just a text hyperlink), you instruct your app to add the UIWebView to the view stack, loading the correct link. You'll want to either do this within a modal view or within a navigation stack so your users can get back out of the web view, of course.

In your MyMainViewController implementation file, something like this:

```
-(void) showWebView {
    // NOTE: I have not tested this, just prototyping 
    // off the top of my head
    UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    myWebView.delegate = self;
    NSURL *homeUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    NSURLRequest *homeRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:homeURL];
    [myWebView loadRequest:homeRequest];
    [self.presentModalViewController: myWebView animated:YES];
    // Don't forget to release objects when you're done
    [myWebView release]; // etc.
}
```

Now, this is off the top of my head from what I know and have done. But I hope you get the general idea. I offer no warranty of any kind here, but do guarantee this is entirely possible with minimal headache. If you get stuck, check out the developer references for UIWebView. Apple's docs are top-notch & show great examples to get you up and running quickly.

Best.

Comment: Great Thanks!!! Do you have any idea about making the url clickable on the home screen of my app without using a button

Comment: Well, I personally wouldn't use anything other than a button. In this case, I'd simply make a button with no style, no background/image, etc. This would make the button look just like a standard text link, with the bonus of it actually being big enough to handle the tap event form a user's finger.